# Automatically locking Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Is it possible to auto-lock the user's desktop whenever Windows 10 is put to sleep? How?

In Windows 8, you could set the desktop profile to automatically lock whenever the laptop was put to sleep. But in Windows 10, we end up waking the laptop only to find ourselves immediately in whoever's profile was last using it.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/222927/how-to-lock-windows-on-sleep ? Or http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/windows-10-lock-on-sleep/16915138-4eac-4a6d-9a03-4deb6b5ee3a0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the require a password on wake-up option within control panel.

1. In Settings > System > Power & Sleep > Additional Power Settings > Require a Password on Wakeup.
2. Click "Change settings that are currently unavailable". (Requires Admin permissions)
3. Edit "Password protection on wakeup", choosing "Require a password (recommended)".